# Custom params for devise login rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, warden, rails-api

I am building an API using Rails 4 and using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for authentication. I am also overriding the `SessionsController` for logging in the user. I have a resource called `user` and have setup the appropriate `devise_for` routes as well. The `create` action is as follows:

```
def create
 self.resource = warden.authenticate(auth_options)
 ## Handle error / success json based on resource
 .......
end
```

Since the resource is `user` if I do a `curl` with the data params like:

```
{"user": {"email": "hello@example.org", "password": "password"} }
```

it works.

All I want to know is how do I customize the parameters, so that `devise/warden` is able to pick it appropriately.
i.e., I would like to send the following request data and it should authenticate:

```
{"email": "hello@example.org", "password": "password"}
```

Comment: you mean that you want them to be nested under a `user` object?

Comment: No. I do not wish it to be nested under an object. It should be like params[:email] and params[:password], instead of params[:user][:email]

Comment: You will probably have to overwrite the devise sessions controller as well as the authenticate method for the resource, check out the article on the wiki for more information https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-Tos#custom-authentication-methods

Answer (score 5):

You can just create your own controller and wrap user parameters with something like this:

```
# app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb
class SessionsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  wrap_parameters :user
end 

# app/config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, controllers: sessions: 'sessions'
```

See [wrap_parameters](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/ParamsWrapper/ClassMethods/wrap_parameters) and [configuring devise controllers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers)

Comment: Hi @alex thanks for letting me know regarding the `wrap_parameters`. Although, using the same `rspec` return a failure.

Comment: @swaroopsm can you debug and see if parameters are properly wrapped now? Error can be caused by something else

Comment: Yes the params are wrapped correctly. When I do a curl request it seems to work fine. But my specs fail! Do I need to include the `ActionController::ParamsWrapper` somewhere in my specs?

Comment: To avoid failures when running the tests, at your specs you must define the content type of the request as being json: `headers = { "CONTENT_TYPE" => "application/json" }` `post endpoint_path, params: my_params.to_json, headers: headers`